# how to find a way for mongodb schema?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I'm new to `MongoDB`. before I start `MongoDB` i was working with `SQL` databases. I know that `MongoDB` is different from `SQL` and in Mongodb you don't have to define a schema. but if you give your database to other teammates and ask him to work with your database, how he can figure out how to work with a `Collection`? in this situation in `SQL`, your teammate will open the database and look at the `Table` and he will understand how to work with it. Suppose according to your analyze, the `User Collection` should hold the following data model:

[image]

But when you have not defined it anywhere, How can you explain it to others?
I hope that I have been able to express my meaning correctly.

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue more clearly, what exactly you want help with

Comment: @KunalMukherjee In SQL you have to define table schema...
But I figured out MongoDB collections is schemaless. 
 In SQL, if you ask your teammate to works with your database, if he sees your tables, he will understand what data model can insert into your tables...

But in MongoDB you have just empty collection(s) where can I define my data model?? In my programming language?

And
if another person wants to works with my database with another language(suppose I'm using Golang and he uses node js) how can I tell him, what model to use?

Comment: You generally [`define`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) your domain model in a programming language like JS or C#